# Problema ao converter int em string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webforms

Estou tentando fazer um contador de cliques em ASP.NET webforms e c#, e preciso converter o número `int` de cliques para uma *string* na *label*. Só que isso não funciona, a página é exibida mas o número de cliques (a *label*) não aparece.

Codigo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Teste
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        int clicks = 0;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clicks++;
            Label1.Text = clicks.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Teste.WebForm2" %>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head runat="server">
    <title>Clickount</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <form runat="server">
      <center>
        <h1>Click counter</h1>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <br />&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Add" CssClass="btn btn-primary"></asp:Button>
    </form>
  </body>

  </html>
```

A única coisa que não faz é exibir o num de cliques, o resto aparece.

Comment: Experimenta trocar a linha que coloca valor no `label` para `Label1.Text = "clicks aqui";` para ver se o problema é a conversão mesmo.

Comment: @bigown a label não aparece igual

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound Como faço isso?

Comment: dê mais detalhes, nós não estamos vendo seu código funcionar, você tem que explicar direito. Mas se mudou e não aparece nada, seu problema não é a conversão, então mude a definição do seu problema ou a pergunta precisa ser fechada por não ser possível reproduzi-lo. Pra mim o botão não está executando. Coloque alguma coisa no método para indicar que passou por ali. Vai *debugando* para ver se entra nesse método. Não tá faltando um `onClick="btn_Click"`?"`

Comment: @bigown o que mais você precisa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema não é a conversão, você apenas esqueceu de vincular o evento `onClick` ao seu botão. Adicione isso na declaração do botão

```
OnClick="btn_Click"
```

Colocando no código

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btn_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary"></asp:Button>
```

Não tenho experiência com *WebForms*, mas acho que salvar o valor de `clicks` numa variável global não irá funcionar. Eu mudaria o evento `onClick` para pegar o valor já existente do `label`.

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int click = Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text); //Se não tiveres certeza do valor de Label1.Text, use o TryParse()
    click++;
    Label1.Text = click.ToString();
}
```

**Obs.:** Dessa forma, o valor de `Label1.Text` deve ser 0 ao carregar a página, se `Label1.Text` for diferente de 0, seria melhor fazer

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int click;
    int.TryParse(Label1.Text, out click); // Se a conversão falhar, click recebe 0
    click++;
    Label1.Text = click.ToString();
}
```

Comment: OK, perfeito, mas meu contador não sai do 1

Comment: Continua igual.

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Nope, deu uma exception

Comment: Que *exception*? Erro de conversão? Se for isso, olhe a resposta.

Comment: Quando aperto o botão, aparece http://imgur.com/jeevPPp

Comment: Funcionou, corrigi

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi o problema é outro. O método não está sendo chamado porque não há evento para ele na definição da página, ficaria assim:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Teste.WebForm2" %>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title>Clickount</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form runat="server">
      <center>
        <h1>Click counter</h1>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <br />&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btn_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary"></asp:Button>
    </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/IntToString.cs).

Answer (score 2):

Dessa forma tu não vai ter êxito em guardar o valor de cada incremento, tu pode jogar as informações diretamente dentro da Label nesse caso em especifico:

```
<h1>Click counter</h1>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" 
        Text="Add" CssClass="btn btn-primary" 
        OnClick="btn_Click">
</asp:Button>
```

Código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Label1.Text = "0";
            }
        }
        protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int quant;
            if (int.TryParse(Label1.Text, out quant))
            {
                quant++;
                Label1.Text = quant.ToString();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

*Observação:* **no seu código faltou vincular o evento do botão ao código, é simples vai para o modo design e dê um duplo clique no botão.**